# Why do I get a HTTP 405 method not allowed?

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to send a request to the following resource, but I get a `HTTP 405 method not allowed`.

```
@Path("/areas")
@Api(tags = "Managin aareas")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public interface AreaResource
{

    @GET
    @ApiOperation(value = "Gets all the areas")
    Response getareas(@Context UriInfo uriInfo);

    @GET
    @Path("/{"+Constants.ID+"}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Finds an area by id")
    Response getAreaById(@PathParam(Constants.ID) String id);

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Creates a new Area")
    Response createArea(Area area);
}
```

I have moved `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` to be on top of only `createArea` but I still get a 405 method not allowed error. What might the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: how are you calling it?

Comment: Since you're sending a JSON object which might cross the length of the GET request, send it as POST instead of GET.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, the possible duplicate thing doesn't really solve my problem. I am not sure where I am wrong.

Comment: Sarah, the curl is doing a GET, but your code is limited to a POST

Comment: @ScaryWombat, but I have added the `@GET` Annotation on top. Will that not work?